# How to rotate a UILabel upside down in XCode, using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to have a label that is displayed upside down, when the view did load.

Here is the default code given in the ViewController.swift, and I had also added the UILabel as an outlet.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Also sorry if this is a dumb question I am very new to IOS development and swift.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To rotate your label in `viewDidLoad` just use the following :

> Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var aLabel: UILabel = ...
    aLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)
}
```

> Objective C

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *aLabel = ...
    aLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
}
```

`M_PI` will make a rotation of 180 degrees which will result in an upside down label.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3x, Xcode 8x

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var aLabel: UILabel = ...
    aLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI))
}
```

Xcode 8.3.3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var aLabel: UILabel = ...
    aLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
}
```